# Silverlight WCF/RIA MVVM Property

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

I've got a Property built in one of my ViewModels that is an integer vs a collection.

```
    private int _formTypeID;
    public int FormTypeID
    {
        get { return _formTypeID; }

        set
        {
            if (_formTypeID == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _formTypeID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FormTypeID");
        }
    }
```

What I'd like to do is to load this from a query from my DomainContext. The query would look something like:

```
    public int GetFormTypeByForm(int Formid)
    {
        var p = (from i in this.ObjectContext.Forms
                where i.FormID == Formid
                select i.FormType).FirstOrDefault();

        return p;
    }
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I will be using this property for loading form specific data and also loading custom column definitions into my XAML.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the parent form present in a collection? If yes your query should work, just use `SingleOrDefault` instead.

Otherwise, you have to load your form to the DomainContext:

```
private int _FormType;
public int FormType
{
  get { return _FormType; }
  set
  {
    if (_FormType == value) return;
    _FormType = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("FormType");
  }
}

public void LoadFormTypeByForm(int Formid)
{
  var query = (from f in this.ObjectContext.Forms
               where f.FormID == Formid
               select f.FormType);

  var action = new Action<LoadOperation<Form>>((op) =>
    {
      if (op.HasError && !op.IsErrorHandled)
      {
        op.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        return;
      }
      var form = ObjectContext.Forms.SingleOrDefault(f => f.FormID == FormID);
      if (form != null)
        FormType = form.FormType;
    });
  Context.Load(query, action, null);
}
```